# Typeahead with responsive table not working correctly

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

has anyone been able to use the type ahead widget within a responsive table? what happens is the overflow of the table cuts off the dropdown list.

any ideas or help would be great!

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you mean by "responsive table"?

Comment: bootstrap supports responsive tables by wrapping your table within a div containing 'table-responsive' class

Comment: The typeahead directive opens a list of matched items, not a table.

Comment: your missing my point. i have a responsive table on my page with a typeahead widget in one of its columns

Comment: Can you show this situation in a jsbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to figure it out. looking at the source code there is a flag you can set to append the dropdown-menu to the body element.

Comment: do you have a code snippet or something? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it on my site [33hotels.com](http://33hotels.com) and it works great. Here is how it looks in my code:

```
<!-- ======= Typeahead directive from Angular UI ======= -->
<input  id="input-region"
        type="search"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="lc.storage.currentRegion"
        typeahead="region as region.nn for region in lc.regionsCompletion($viewValue) | filter:{n:$viewValue}"
        typeahead-template-url="typeahead.tpl.html"
        typeahead-wait-ms="0"
        typeahead-loading="loadingRegions"
        typeahead-on-select="lc.updateRegion()"
        placeholder="Enter your region"
        ng-blur="lc.onBlur()"
        focus-on="locationFocus"
        autofocus/>
```

I have a custom Bootstrap though, disabling most of the declarations. You can play with my site in your Chrome inspector and see what declarations are there.

Comment: i don't see a responsive table like I said in my question.